# -bash: !'@10.109.10.142/?ip=10.109.8.39: event not found

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I have this command:

```
ovftool --acceptAllEulas -ds="Local_Storage_1_39" -n="VR-OVF" --net:"Management Network"="VM Network 2" --prop:"password"="R3d@ctedPassw0rd!"$a" --prop:"ntpserver"="10.109.10.140" --prop:"vami.ip0.vSphere_Replication_Appliance"="10.109.10.198" --vService:installation=com.vmware.vim.vsm:extension_vservice /mnt/iso/bin/vSphere_Replication_OVF10.ovf vi://"administrator@vmware.local":'R3d@ctedPassw0rd!'@10.109.10.142/?ip=10.109.8.39
```

The output is:

```
-bash: !'@10.109.10.142/?ip=10.109.8.39: event not found
```

I tried Providing the password within single quotes. Same thing. I tried:
`\"'R3d@ctedPassw0rd!'\"` and still the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event not found` indicates a failed shell history search.  This is probably due to badly-paired quoting around your password which includes a `!`, so your shell (`bash`) is trying to parse it into a history expansion, failing to do so, and throwing up its metaphorical hands and returning the error message:

```
$ echo Problems!Abound
bash: !Abound: event not found
```

Weak quotes won't protect against this:

```
$ echo "Problems!Abound"
-bash: !Abound: event not found
```

Either put your password into a variable and refer to it indirectly, or ensure that your password is always either enclosed in strong quotes (as below) or properly escaped:

```
$ echo 'Problems!Abound'
Problems!Abound
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in quotes earlier in this part of your command.

```
--prop:"password"="R3d@ctedPassw0rd"$a"
```

If you paste the command into an editor that can do syntax highlighting the problem is easy to spot.  I'm not sure what is in the variable `$a`, but I would guess you need to remove the quote immediately before it to make the option look like this:

```
--prop:"password"="R3d@ctedPassw0rd$a"
```

Comment: You've missed the `!` history event problem entirely

Comment: @roaima: The `!` was in his password (his original post showed it there before he edited it to obfuscate the password) which he has surrounded by single quotes (`'`), so it should have been properly protected.  The reason it was a problem was because of the extra quote I mentioned in my response.  That's why I didn't mention the `!` history event -- it wasn't the source of his problem.

Comment: Apologies. I'd seen the original from the edit history and (on my mobile) I missed that the OP had used single quotes to try and protect the exclamation mark. If you can edit your post slightly (doesn't really matter what) I'll adjust my vote for you. I'll also remove my earlier comment - and this one later.